# Redirect http to https on home page only

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I read many similar questions but I did not find a solution. I want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the home page only.

- `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`

I don't know anything about `.htacces`.

Here you can see how it looks now, it contains code to hide `.php` extensions, expires caching and redirect www to non-www. I found these examples online:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54  .php54 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect only the homepage to HTTPS (and canonicalise the www subdomain) then add the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://%1/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK to avoid browser caching issues.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Your existing www to non-www redirect at the end of the file also needs to be modified, otherwise it will redirect the homepage back to `HTTP`. This should also be moved to the top of your `.htaccess` file, immediately after the HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that I changed `^(.*)$` to `^(.+)$` to match 1 or more characters - thus avoiding the homepage. You can also simplify this to `(.+)` (ie. remove the anchors) if you wish. Regex is greedy by default, the anchors are superfluous.

### Summary

```
RewriteEngine On

# Only redirect homepage to HTTPS (and remove www subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://%1/ [R=302,L]

# Remove www subdomain on other pages (HTTP only)
# >>> This is moved from the end of the htaccess file
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) http://%1/$1 [R=302,L]

# Remainder of htaccess file....
:
:
```

Clear your browser cache and change `302` to `301` only once you have confirmed it's working OK.

---

*Aside:* You can remove the `RewriteEngine` directive that appears later in the file if you wish. This is optional, it only *needs* to occur once. Being at the top, before the mod_rewrite directives, is logical (but not strictly required).

Comment: Updated answer... fixed regex to make group non-capturing, so that the `%1` backreference always matches the domain, less the _optional_ `www` prefix.

Comment: I think it works, can you check my updated code and confirm it is ok?

Comment: Your updated code doesn't show the HTTP to HTTPS redirect for the homepage? I've updated my answer with a "summary".